# Vectorstore with a kor library (on top of langchain)

Tags: langchain

I am testing a kor library and I find it really helpful when extracting pieces of information from a low-quality text (like parsed online ads). The problem is a kor prompt usually gets long and when combined with an original text, it easily exceeds the token limit of OpenAI.

When working with pure LangChain, I use vectorstores to grab the most relevant chunks of text.

Do you know how to use vectorstores with kor? That would really help! Thanks.

I tried to pass retriever as an argument to kor's create_extraction_chain, but it does not work.

chain = create_extraction_chain(llm, schema, retriever=new_store.as_retriever())